# Building dynamic lambda expressions

Tags: dynamic, lambda, tree, expression, expression-trees

I know how to build a simple lambda like *x => x > 5*:

```
int[] nbs = new[] { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10 };            
IEnumerable<int> result1 = nbs.Where(x => x > 5);

ParameterExpression parameter = Expression.Parameter(typeof(int), "x");
ConstantExpression constant = Expression.Constant(5);
BinaryExpression expressionBody = Expression.GreaterThan(parameter, constant);
Expression<Func<int, bool>> expression = Expression.Lambda<Func<int, bool>>(expressionBody, parameter);
IEnumerable<int> result2 = nbs.Where(expression.Compile());
```

But how do I build a lambda like *x => whiteNbs.Contains(x)* in a similar way as above:

```
int[] nbs = new[] { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10 };
List<int> whiteNbs = new List<int>() { 1, 5 };            
IEnumerable<int> result = nbs.Where(x => whiteNbs.Contains(x));
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Replace binary `GreaterThan` expression with a `MethodCallExpression`.

```
int[] nbs = new[] { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10 };

var elementType = typeof(int);
var x = Expression.Parameter(elementType, "x");
var whiteNbs = Expression.Constant(new List<int>() {1, 5});

var contains = Expression.Call(typeof(Enumerable),
    "Contains",
    new[] {elementType},
    whiteNbs, 
    x
  );

var lambda = Expression.Lambda<Func<int, bool>>(contains, x);
var result = nbs.Where(lambda.Compile());
```